# LaTeX hexagonal chains

Tags: latex, graph-theory, tex, tikz, overleaf

I am using LaTeX for research with hexagonal chains and would like to know some ways to create the a horizontal hexagonal chain. So far I only have some going vertically; I have used code I received on here under a previous question but haven't figured out how to rotate the vertical chain of hexagons to make it horizontal.

Is it possible to use chemfig or tikz to create a chain similar to either of these?

[image: Hexagonal chain of 3 hexagons]

[image: Hexagonal chain with dotted line representing any number of hexagons]

Comment: @whoever voted to migrate this to tex.se: don't migrate this! The author already has cross-posted the same question, so it would have to be closed as duplicate. No advantage of migrating this post.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666843/horizontal-hexagonal-chains-chemfig-tikz

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the `chemfig` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\chemfig{*6(--*6(--*6(-----)---)----)}
\caption{Chain of 3 hexagons}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the corresponding output
[image]